# What are discriminated records in Ada?

Tags: record, ada

I'm trying to understand what discriminated records are in Ada but couldnt find a clear cut, precise answer online.

For example what makes this an discriminated record:

```
type Discriminated_Record (Size : Natural) is 
    record
       A : String (1 .. Size);
    end record;
```

Comment: You can see a discriminated record in Ada as union in C/C++. It just means that by the given argument(s) you select the fields from that record (in C you would do something like `stVar.a` or `stVar.b`, where `stVar` is a union struct with `a` and `b` being its fields of possibly different types or layout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a discriminated *type* because it has a discriminant, and it’s a discriminated *record* because it’s a record. Other types that can have discriminants are task and protected types.

For a discriminated object, the discriminant is just another component (aside from being immutable). So given

```
type Buffer(Size : Buffer_Size := 100)  is
   record
      Pos   : Buffer_Size := 0;
      Value : String(1 .. Size);
   end record;

B : Buffer (Size => 50);
```

you can access `B.Size` (which will be the same as `B.Value’Length`).

Comment: Technically `B.Value'Last`.  The type of `B.Value'Length` is universal integer, not `Buffer_Size`.

Comment: Note that it is not possible to reassign B with a value that has a different discriminant. The discriminant is part of the type, so two types differing only in the discriminant are incompatible. I believe that also means the [wiki entry regarding optionals in Ada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type#Ada) is incorrect; the Optional_Type suggested is useless because you can only use it to represent a constant optional.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn - constant objects are useful: you could have a function returning a value of this optional type.

Answer (score 3):

The discriminant, `Size`, makes `Discriminated_Record` a discriminated record.

Comment: so size is the `discriminant` and discriminated records are parametrized records. right ?

Comment: Yes, commonly used for arrays whose bounds may vary at run-time.

Comment: @zython, yes, see [ARM 3.7(1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-7.html#p1)

Comment: @oenone, ARM 3.7(1) says explicitly that arrays, not being composite, can’t have discriminants. Constraints, yes.